# Javascript Change Image When Mouse Over Another

Tags: javascript, html, image

What I'm looking to do is change an image (Info Box) to a different image (Info Box A) when hovering over a separate image (Image A).  I should also note that the solution would need to be flexible enough to allow for the Info Box to change into an assortment of different images (Info Box A, B, C,...) when hovering over the separate but corresponding images (Image A, B, C,...).  There will also be multiple sets of Info Boxes and Images. If it helps at all to visualize or conceptualize what I'm looking to accomplish this page is what I'm working on: http://www.cupofcomics.com/library/

Currently the general code that I'm working with is:

Java Script

```
window.onload = function(){ 
  var pic = document.getElementById("pic"); 
  var HlPica = document.getElementById("otherPic"); 
  oPic.onmouseover = function(){ 
     pic.src = "http://cupofcomics.com/images/library/info/headliners/HlPicaInfo.png"; 
  } 
  oPic.onmouseout = function(){ 
  pic.src = "http://cupofcomics.com/images/library/info/infonull.png"; 
  } 
}
```

HTML

```
<img id="otherPic" src="http://cupofcomics.com/images/library/bindings/headliners/HlPica.png"> 
<img id="pic" src="http://cupofcomics.com/images/library/info/infonull.png">
```

I am open to solutions outside of javascript but the research I did led me to the belief that javascript is the easiest solution.  I'm incredibly amateurish when it comes to coding in all senses but as far as I understand javascript, I'm not sure what I'm missing. Thanks.

full current code: http://jsfiddle.net/monotypical/5bGMw/1/

Comment: Egads. A fiddle doesn't need to be nearly so complex.

Comment: jquery is fine!!  and here is a stripped down fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/monotypical/me9Af/

Comment: `http://www.cupofcomics.com/library/info/headliners/HlPicainfo.png` im getting page not found.. your events are working.. kindly double check your images

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @drixson-osena! However even after I've updated the images it still doesn't seem to respond. http://jsfiddle.net/monotypical/me9Af/4/

Comment: Working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/me9Af/5/

Comment: The main problem with your full code is, you have multiple window.onload = function () calls. This is invalid, it overwrites the each other and only the last window.onload handler will work.

Comment: @SajithNair thank you so much, but I must ask, is there a reason that the javascript will only work if it's called for in the html in your working fiddle?  I'm ultimately working in wordpress and so often script tags don't work.

Comment: It will work from Javascript box also, but instead of assigning function to window.load, you will need to bind it to onload handler.